# Is okio 1.9.0 backward compatible with okio 1.2.0?

Tags: okio

My project depends on a couple of third party libraries, which bring in `okio` v. 1.9.0 and 1.2.0, respectively.

Can I count on backward compatibility, and just use `okio` version 1.9.0 (in place of 1.2.0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all 1.x versions of Okio are API-compatible. Check the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/square/okio/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for details.